# How to set the different legend icon for different series in same chart

Tags: echarts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGLn.png)

As shown in the figure above, I need to remove the circle in the middle of the third icon, but keep the shape of the other two charts rectangular.But when I set `legend.icon = 'line'`, the shape of the other two icons changed.What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

Nobody in the world knows that you did wrong because no one has seen your code but `legend` [supports separate icons](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.data) for each series.

```js
var option = {
  //...
  legend: {
    data: [
      { name: 'Series1', icon: 'circle'   }, 
      { name: 'Series2', icon: 'triangle' }, 
      { name: 'Series3', icon: 'diamond'  }, 
    ]
  }
  //...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const option = {
  legend: {
    data: [
      { name: 'Series1', icon: 'circle' },
      { name: 'Series2', icon: 'triangle' },
      { name: 'Series3', icon: 'diamond' },
    ],
  },
  data: [
    {
      name: 'Series1',
      icon: 'circle',
    },
    {
      name: 'Series2',
      icon: 'rect',
    },
  ],
};
```